# visual studio highlighting all @ blocks

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2019

I don't understand why this is happening. Can't find anything online or in the settings to turn it off. IF anyone knows how to turn this off I'd appreciate the advice.

[image: highlighting]

Comment: I suspect what you might be seeing is **HTML Server Side Script** highlighting.  If you want to experiment, try selecting Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors then scroll through **Display items** to find `HTML Server Script`.  Select that item and see if the Item Background is yellow.  If it is, change it some something else (Lime?) and click on OK.  Then check to see if your highlights have changed to your new color.  If they did change, now you know what display item controls that color you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font colors and backgrounds are defined in Tools -> Options (see below). I'm not sure which Display item is for the @ symbol, but you should be able to tell by the Item background being the yellow you are seeing. You can change to whatever you want.

[image: VS Options Page]

See generic docuumentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-the-editor?view=vs-2019